# VMware Workstation 12 Suspend VM, disadvantages?

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation, pause

Im working with VMware Workstation 12 and I never Suspend my Virtual Machines, because I don't trust the option to Suspend your Machine. Today I was searching about 2 hours, if there are any disadvantages in supsending your VM, but I couldn't find any.

I just can't belive that there aren't any other disadvantages than losing some little space on your local computer.

**Have I missed something, or is suspending really that safe and good to use?**

Info: All my VMs are running on Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of resource consumption Suspend needs to save VM's current state, therefore used memory should be dumped to `.vmss` file. Creating this file and saving it - this is overhead you have.

Comment: Nice answer, but I want to know if there is anything BAD about suspending your VM, like loosing data or something like that.

Comment: I have not been facing anything weird and what do you mean by _BAD_ ? No data loss or data corruption observed :) . Of course, if you have OLTP process running inside VM  - like MSSQL/ Postgres - I don't think suspending will be a good choice unless you can gracefully finish transactions with VSS (volume shadow copy or similar technique)

Comment: Thanks! That was the answer I hoped for :D